# Filtering dataset to a certain date values in PBI DAX

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, dax

I have the following table  tbl_Homeless , with [# Homeless] measure:

[image]

I need to add a filter or to modify my measure, so that it could be only shown the data where
[Month] is at least within 12 months period or more.
In the case shown on a picture it should be only data in blue.
Data that are non marked in blue (ClientID = 44) needed to be filtered out.
Because the [Month] of those data is less than 12 Months period.

After applying a filter to [# Homeless] measure, I expect to have the following dataset
(without data where ClientID = 44):
[image]

My code should be something like:

```
updated_Homeless = Calculate([# Homeless], Filter....
```

But I don't know how to apply filter for my [Month] field

Comment: Why don't you want to make a slicer of the Month Column and filter then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not try this? Please run the code to check the result.

```
updated_Homeless_Measure =
VAR LastDate =
    MAX ( tbl_Homeless[Month] )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE (
        [# Homeless],
        DATESINPERIOD ( tbl_Homeless[Month], LastDate, -12, MONTH )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

But I think You expect your DAX code to return a table, not a scalar values as a measure does. So Create "New Table" command, then paste this code, It returns a table:

```
updated_Homeless_Table =
VAR LastDate =
    MAX ( tbl_Homeless[Month] )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        tbl_Homeless,
        DATESINPERIOD ( tbl_Homeless[Month], LastDate, -12, MONTH )
    )
RETURN
    Result
```